# Installing meld 3.13.0 on Mac OS X (either natively or by homebrew)

Tags: python, macos, meld

I used to have meld 1.8.6 installed on my iMac and meld 3.13 installed on my Ubuntu.  Now I need to work with people from Taiwan and I am preparing them the Traditional Chinese version of the software.  Since some of them uses MacBook Air, I need to prepare the steps for them to install the software.

The meld 1.8.6 used to work with homebrew, but now the formula has gone.  Also, I need some new features of the newer version that I prefer running meld 3.13.  I knew that the software is completely written in python, and Mac OS X has got python installed.  However, meld 3.13 failed to run for the following error:

```
Couldn't bind the tranlsation domain.  Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'
Cannot import: GTK+
No module named gi
```

I wish I can compile the program into binary and distribute it, but I have no idea about how to do so?  Have any of you got a similar experience?  How do you solve it? Can I solve it by installing additional packages through homebrew?

Comment: I also am trying to accomplish this. I'll let you know if I find something that works.

Comment: Tried another time.  Still not working.  I am thinking if there is some missing library links or not.

Comment: the "No module named gi" issue can be solved by "sudo -H pip install gi".  But the GTK+ issue still persist.  And then it turns out another one missing "No module named repository", which cannot be found by either pip or brew.